# Linq To XML - Using XDocument and creating list of objects

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have  to read an `XML` document and insert the values into a `List<T>` of my objects.

### Class (Result)

```
+Result
-username
-dob
-answer1
-answer2
-uuid
```

### Below is the XML format structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<export exportDate="2012-11-07T12:03:52.823+11:00">
    <survey type="USER" completion="2012-11-07T11:46:52.754+11:00" reference="2012-11-07T11:30:34.680+11:00" year="2012" uuid="226f2aa3-46e6-46ab-8995-7d52eb21d5f4">
        <user xsi:type="USER" created="2012-11-07T11:09:30.409+11:00" dob="08/06/1988" surname="Billy" name="Bob" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <subject created="2012-11-07T11:09:30.409+11:00" dob="08/06/1988" surname="Billy" name="Bob"/>
        <version released="1970-01-01T10:00:02.012+10:00" version="1"/>
        <result group="2" rawscore="2.4" metric="1"/>
        <result group="2" rawscore="2.0" metric="2"/>
        <answer score="1" question="6"/>
        <answer score="2" question="7"/>
    </survey>       
</export>
```

### My current progress

I was previously using **XmlDocument** as I have in the past but now that Im working with Linq im sure this can be done in just a few lines. I dont like the look of the code below, if anyway has some tips please help.

thankyou

```
    List<Result> results = new List<Result>();

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(filename); 

    XmlNodeList objects = doc.GetElementsByTagName("survey"); 
    foreach (XmlNode o in objects)
    {
        Result result = new Result();

        if (o.Attributes["type"].Value == "USER" || o.Attributes["type"].Value == "ADMIN")
        {
            result.surveycompleted = o.Attributes["completion"].Value;

            XmlNodeList usernodes = o.SelectNodes("user");
                ....
            if (usernodes.Count > 0)
            {}
            else
            {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LINQ2XML:

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load(filename);
List<Result> lstSurvey=doc.DescendantsAndSelf("Survey").Select(x=>
new Result
{
    uuid=x.Element("Survey").Attribute("uuid").Value,
    username=x.Element("user").Attribute("name").Value,
    dob=x.Element("user").Attribute("dob").Value,
    answer1=x.Elements("answer").First().Value,
    answer2=x.Elements("answer").Skip(1).First().Value
}
).ToList<Result>();
```

Comment: The third line "new" does this create a un named object, should I use "new Result {"

Comment: @IEnumerable ohh..sorry..you can use `Result`..check out the edit

Comment: Thanks, very nice code by the way, Im learning Linq for the past 5 weeks so Im a bit of a newbie. The other thing I have is over 120 "answers"/nodes. could this part of the Linq be in a sub loop?. If so how are the sub selects/loops created ?

Comment: @IEnumerable there is no need of loop..`DescendantsAndSelf("Survey")` would give all the survey nodes..and then in the `select` we are accessing each of the nodes within the Survey node

Comment: - thanks, what i have is over 120 answer nodes, to match them to the object property I used a Linq inner select as the answer id is a XmlAttribute. Below is my code Ive been figuring out in the past 30 min .

    Also, Is there a better way to post code rather than in comments ?

                    answer1 = (from e in x.Elements("answer")
                    where e.Attribute("question").Value == "1"
                         select     e.Attribute("score").Value).SingleOrDefault(),